# how do I read the file data and upload it?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am making a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse using Spring(4) MVC and Hibernate(4), I want to upload the data (file will contain large number of phone numbers) of a file to a table in mysql, so how do I read the file data and upload it?

Comment: You can add a `<input type="file">` in your UI and cosume it in the controller as a multipart type data and store it in the DB as a byte array (Probably BLOB)

Comment: @TinoMThomas Thank you for your prompt reply, I also wanted to know that how shall I save this file in a POJO class and then using Hibernate I would upload the data?

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section before asking a question so that the SO community can get a better understanding of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile` in Spring MVC to upload file

Add method in Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/processUpload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody RateResponse<String> processContractUpload(@RequestParam("txtFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        String result = "failure";
        String outFile = "C:\\temp\file.txt"
        if(file != null && file.getSize()>0){
            byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
            BufferedOutputStream stream = null;
            try{
                stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
                stream.write(bytes);
                result = "success";
            }finally {
                if(stream!=null){
                    stream.close(); 
                }
            }

        }

        return result;
    }
```

HTML Form

```
<form id="uploadContractForm" name="uploadContractForm" action="processUpload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">        

<table class="tableStyle">
    <tr>

        <td><input type="file" name="txtFile" id="txtFile" style="background:white;" class="summaryTextSpan4"/></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td><input id="processbtn" type="button"  class="btn" value='Submit' /></td>
        <td><input id="refreshBtn" class="btn" type="button"  value='Reset' /></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Spring bean configuration required to enable Spring Multipart

```
<!-- File Upload Configuration Bean Details  -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
          <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000000" /> 
    </bean>
```

For file upload to DB sample you can [read here](http://learningsolo.com/spring-mvc-excel-file-upload-to-oracle-database-example/) 

also working sample can be downloaded [from here](https://github.com/sushilsingh94/Spring-Examples/tree/master/SpringFileUploadToDB) on github

Comment: Thank you so much @Sushil, I'm almost doing this only but I want to save this file data to a table in MySQL using hibernate instead of saving it on the drive.

Comment: what type of file data are you trying to upload. You can read file from disk using BufferedReader and convert to java object. Then it can be stored into DB as using DAO...  BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(fileLocation),Charset.forName("UTF-8")));

Comment: I have updated my answer with working sample code link. Hope that solves your problem. https://github.com/sushilsingh94/Spring-Examples/tree/master/SpringFileUploadToDB

Comment: Got it ! Thanks @Sushil

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below links

1. [File upload](https://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-single-multiple-files)
2. [Hibernate binary data mapping](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/hibernate-binary-data-and-blob-mapping-example)